# Youtube API Python Quickstart: OAuth Client ID Application type: No option 'Other'

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

[No option 'Other' available in menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWskD.png)

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/python. In the Python quickstart guide, in step 2 b), we are asked to choose Application type as 'Other'. However, such an option does not appear. I tried using 'Web Application', despite knowing it wouldn't work, but got an error when it came to authenticating it. Should I be using another app type? Please help me out.

Comment: You should go for the `Desktop App` option. It should work, since the doc you have mentioned is about a Python CLI app making requests to Youtube's Data API.

Comment: There now seems to be another error. When I try visiting the authorization url that is an output of the python program, google says that it is 'not verified by google'. Please help.

Comment: Unverified apps are specified for example by [this doc](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/7454865?hl=en&ref_topic=7013279). For time being you may ignore that your app is not yet verified.